# Test python requests with current running server

Tags: python, python-requests, odoo

The request call does not respond with the current running server in localhost.

I have a script like this:

```
import requests

params = {
    'access_token': 'access_token'
}
response = requests.get('http://localhost/something', params=params)
```

I was running when I started localhost server and call direct

```
python test_code.py
```

But I want to move it inside test, call it each time I upgrade server. Actually it's running but stuck at `response = requests.get('http://localhost/something', params=params)`

```
class TestAPI(common.TransactionCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestAPI, self).setUp()

    def test_request(self):
        params = {
            'access_token': 'access_token'
        }
        response = requests.get('http://localhost/something', params=params)
```

Is there any way I can achieve that, `mock` or something, I heard about `mock` but can't find the way to apply it.

Comment: Please post your server code

Comment: I actually running Odoo Server from the command line: `./odoo/odoo-bin -c config/server.conf`